# How to show input value and label from a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Goal: Show a label, and input value from a different div and display it in a different section

I have a div that dynamically generates a set of input fields, and I am trying to then display that input fields value and their corresponding labels in a different section.

For example: 
Step 1 - User enters in the number 5 into an input field. 
Step 2 - There are 5 input fields created (based on value entered from step 1). Those input fields are labeled #1, #2, #3, etc... all the way to #5 or whatever number the user entered in Step 1. 
Step 3 - User is presented with a new HTML section that lists off the labels (#1, #2, #3, etc.) and next to the labels is the value the user entered for those corresponding input fields.

Here is the code created for Step 2:

```
    <label>#' + count + '</label>
    <input type="number" name="length_field" value="" class="form-control length_field" />
```

Then, I need some javascript/jquery to take the labels and their corresponding input values and display then something like this:

```
    <p>[LABEL #1] <span>[LABEL #1 INPUT VALUE]</span></p>
    <p>[LABEL #2] <span>[LABEL #2 INPUT VALUE]</span></p>
    <p>[LABEL #3] <span>[LABEL #3 INPUT VALUE]</span></p>
```

Etc...

Comment: Have you tried to write any JavaScript?

Comment: Not for this functionality (I'm still a beginner at JS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For step 2 you need to check the value of your `length_field` input and create that many inputs by JavaScript. Set some helper ID and CLASS attributes so you can get values later. 
For step 3 use that attributes to get input field values and set them as result div's html.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#length_field', function() {
  var inputsCount = parseInt($(this).val());

  $('#inputsWrapper').html('');
  $('#result').html('');

  for (var i = 1; i <= inputsCount; i++) {
    // Create custom input with label
    var tempInput = document.createElement('input');
    tempInput.setAttribute('name', i);
    tempInput.setAttribute('id', i);
    tempInput.setAttribute('class', 'customInputs');
    
    var tempInputLabel = document.createElement('label');
    tempInputLabel.setAttribute("for", i);
    tempInputLabel.innerHTML = 'Input #' + i + ": ";
    $('#inputsWrapper').append(tempInputLabel);
    $('#inputsWrapper').append(tempInput);

    // Create corresponding value presenter in result div
    var resultRow = document.createElement('p');
    resultRow.setAttribute('id', 'result-' + i);
    resultRow.innerHTML = 'Label #' + i + ':';
    $('#result').append(resultRow);
  }
});

$(document).on('keyup', '.customInputs', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var inputValue = $(this).val();
  
  $('#result-' + id).html('Label #' + id + ': <span> ' + inputValue + '</span>');
});
```

```css
#inputsWrapper input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="length_field">Enter the number of inputs you want:</label>
<input type="number" name="length_field" id="length_field" />

<br/>

<div id="inputsWrapper">
</div>

<hr>

<div id="result">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really quick'n'dirty but it works.

I'm using a for-loop in both steps, in the first step the for-loop is generating the input fields and outputting them after.

In the second step I'm saving the html of the resulting paragraphs in a variable, because I can't override the document, because my wanted values are in the input fields.

The on keypress listener is optional and ensures that you don't have to press the Submit button with your mouse ;)

If I could help you i would appreciate if you could mark this answer as accepted.

```js
let number = 0;

$(document).on("click", "#step1", function() {
  number = $("input").val();
  if (number > 0) {
    let html = "", i;
    for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
      html += "<label for='input_" + i + "'>#" + i + "</label>: <input type='text' id='input_" + i + "'><br>";
    }
    html += "<button id='step2'>Submit</button>"
    $("body").html(html);
  }
})

$(document).on("click", "#step2", function() {
  let html = "", i;
  for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    html += "<p>Label #" + i + ": <span>" + $("#input_" + i).val() + "</span></p>";
  }
  $("body").html(html);
})

$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $("button").trigger("click");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" placeholder="Number of fields">
<button id="step1">Submit</button>
```